# Differences between Python and Julia convolutions?

Tags: python, julia, convolution

I'm trying to convert a section of code from Python to Julia and I'm having a hard time understanding the output differences between the following convolutions:

Python:

```
conc = [10,100,1000,5,2000,200,20]
conc_filter = [1,2,3]
sp.ndimage.convolve1d(conc, conc_filter,axis=0,mode='constant')
```

Output:`[ 120, 1230, 2305, 5010, 4215, 6420,  640]`

Julia:

```
conc = [10,100,1000,5,2000,200,20]
conc_filter = [1,2,3]
conv(conc,conc_filter)
```

Output: `[10, 120, 1230, 2305, 5010, 4215, 6420,  640, 60]`

Can anyone explain why the output lengths are different? In an attempt to recreate the Python output, I've tried to come up with a logical formula that relates the input/filter sizes with the index range required to slice the conv output and obtain the same result. However, I haven't had much luck. Is there a Julia function that can produce the same output?

Comment: What version of Julia are you using and where did the `conv` function come from?

Comment: In your Julia code, the input array has 7 elements but the output has 9 elements. Is that correct?

Comment: @StevenSiew Running the OP's Julia code in version 1.0.0 I get the same 9 elements.  (Also, the OP may be running a version before 1.0 since the DSP package has been removed from the "base" language.)  OTOH, the OP may not have included the add DSP and using DSP commands in his question's code.

Comment: They are both correct, they are simply handling boundary conditions in different ways.

Comment: @DNF It seems like you could write up your comments as an answer.  You may well have solved the OP's problem.

Comment: Julia shows the entire transient response of the discrete convolution.  Your Python version doesn't include the full response probably because it wants to preserve the original vector length.  As a default, I prefer convolution/filter routines to return the entire response.  I can trim the "edges" if I want/need to.  Some DSP packages include switches to their convolution/filter routines to provide either a full (including transient) response, a vector length preserving response, or just a steady state response.

Comment: I'm using Julia 0.6.2 in JuliaBox which includes the DSP package I believe? @rickhg12hs , a function to 'trim the edges' is exactly what I'm looking for. As far as I can work out, there doesn't seem to be an argument in the conv function that lets me do this.

Comment: Trimming the edges is just a matter of indexing the convolution vector.  If the convolution function doesn't have "edge selection" options builtin, you can just directly index what you want (or make a view).  Of course, that means you need to know exactly what the convolution function is producing, and exactly what you want.  You could write your own composite function that accepts the same parameters as the original function, calls the original function, and then returns, in this case, the trimmed vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those interested, I worked out the padding scheme used in the 'constant' mode, passed as a parameter to the Python convolution function. The difficulty in finding a relationship between the input/output sizes was due to the way left and right padding is done for symmetric vs unsymmetric convolution filters.

The Julia code below seems to match the Python equivalent for all tested input/outputs.

```
conc = [10,100,1000,5,2000,200,20]
conc_filter = [1,2,3]

n=length(conc)
m=length(conc_filter)

padleft=ceil(Int32,m/2)-1
padright=floor(Int32,m/2)

conc =append!(zeros(padleft),conc)
conc = append!(conc,zeros(padright))

out = zeros(n)
for i in 1:n
    for j in 1:m
        out[i] += conc[i+j-1]*conc_filter[m-j+1]
    end
end
out
```

Result: 
    [ 120, 1230, 2305, 5010, 4215, 6420,  640]

Answer (score 2):

What Python conv routine are you using? Here is Python's numpy convolve:

```
>>> conc = [10,100,1000,5,2000,200,20]
>>> conc_filter = [1,2,3]

>>> numpy.convolve(conc, conc_filter,axis=0,mode='constant')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: convolve() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'

>>> numpy.convolve(conc, conc_filter)
array([  10,  120, 1230, 2305, 5010, 4215, 6420,  640,   60])
```

You might need to peek at the documentation to your Python package and see how to make fft() type routines do what you need.

Comment: I want to stick with the length preserving version as it works with the rest of the model I'm working on. My hope is that I can do the opposite conversion - i.e. change the Julia code so that it replicates the ndimage.convolve1d output.

Comment: If you are always using a 3-element second vector for convolution, you might just take array[2: end-1] to drop first and last elements.

Comment: Unfortunately, the 3-element filter above is just an example. I'm trying to come up with something that will work for all input and filter lengths.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand your question correctly:

According to [this](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/34434/vector-length-output-of-discrete-time-convolution) answer on stackexchange, the vector length of the Julia example is correct.

N + M - 1 gives an output vector length of 9, as shown by the Julia answer.

Are you sure the Python code and/or copied output is correct?

Comment: The correct vector length is a matter of definition. Normally, you get `N+M-1`, but it is common to want to preserve the length of the original vector. In that case you can specify boundary conditions such as constant (e.g. zero-padded), periodic, reflective, etc. etc. If you use a periodic boundary condition, the convolution can be implemented with the FFT, which can be very efficient in many cases.

Comment: @DNF so do you know if there is a length-preserving convolution in Julia? I haven't had any luck Googling/searching the Julia docs.